# Bulk insert over stored procedure on a mysql database using Dapper

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, dapper, bulkinsert

I am trying to do an insert of multiple rows at once using a stored procedure. On MSSQL I could use the UDT's/ Table Parameters to do a bulk insert, but on mysql this is not supported.
Other than iteration of insert one row at a time by code and LOAD DATA INFILE. Is there a solution?

My stored procedure would look like this for a table Foo with two fields Id and Name.

```
create procedure InsertMultiple(
    in id int,
    in name varchar(50)
)
BEGIN
    insert into Foo (Id, Name) values (id, name);
END$$
```

What I want to pass in is multiple records of id, name so that multiple rows can be created at once.

Let me know if I have missed any information on the description. Thanks for your time!

Was also trying to find something on the Dapper documentation, but no luck so far.

https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper#execute-a-command-multiple-times
this resambles it with in code query, switching to sp on my tests I have gotten the Exception Enumerable types are not supported in this context.

Have also tried passing in all these in Dynamic Parameters, but same exception.

```
            DynamicParameters par = new();
            foreach (var r in items)
            {
               parameters.Add(new
                {
                    id = r.Id,
                    name = r.Name
                });
            }
```

Comment: Bulk data loading with MySQL is typically done using MySQL's own command-line tools instead of through SQL - as of MySQL 8.0 the preferred tool for doing this is the [MySQL Shell](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/), specifically consider the _Parallel Table Import Utility_: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-utilities-parallel-table.html - additionally, [MySQL supports `INSERT` with multiple `VALUES` tuples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could try sending a JSON type in MySQL.

```
create procedure InsertMultiple(
    in items JSON
)
BEGIN
    insert into Foo (Id, Name) values (JSON_EXTRACT(items, '$[0].id', '$[1].name');
END$$
```

From managed code, simply serialize the param.

```
DynamicParameters par = new();
par.Add(new {items = JsonSerializer.Serialize(items)});
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html

Comment: This was what worked for me indeed, thank you very much for it @beautifulcoder!
The part of the stored procedure was a little tricky as it was a bit more complicated that I expected, but all good! Thank you!